# cakePHP in sub -directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I am using cakePHP 3 to develop application.
On localhost, my webpage went great, once I put it on server, into folder, it started to do errors like this.

> Internal Server Error
>        The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>        Please contact the server administrator at ssl@atlantis.sk to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>        More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

or when I played with .htaccess a little it started do this error:

> The requested URL /php-fastcgi/php5/webroot/index.php was not found on
>   this server.

my .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

It was necessary to add this line in .htaccess because of version

`AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp7 .php`

Thanks.